# How to add incremental data into a file in spark SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am have 2 parquet file one is with full load data and one is with only latest date data.
I want to add latest date data into full load data without any duplicates. that means if any record in latest date are also in full load data I want to just update that. I was trying do this using spark SQL.

```
var SourcePath=s"/mnt/HeN/"
val VW_HISTORY_MAIN=spark.read.format("parquet").option("header","true")
  .load(s"${SourcePath}/VW_HISTORY")
VW_HISTORY_MAIN.createOrReplaceTempView("full")

val VW_HISTORY_UPDATE=spark.read.format("parquet").option("header","true")
  .load(s"${SourcePath}/VW_HISTORY_UPDATE")
VW_HISTORY_UPDATE.createOrReplaceTempView("update")
```

Kindly suggest how can I do the same?

Update:

After I am having above two parquet files.
Created delta table for VW_HISTORY.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VW_HISTORY1(
key  struct<in_id:string,.....>, 
  mem_key string, 
  .....                                                                                     

  ) USING DELTA
  LOCATION "/FileStore/tables/VW_HISTORY"
```

Other Delta table for VW_HISTORY_UPDATE.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VW_HISTORY_UPDATE1(
  in_id string, 
  ......
  ) USING DELTA
  LOCATION "/FileStore/tables/HEN/VW_HISTORY_UPDATE"
```

Then I have loaded VW_HISTORY parquet file into VW_HISTORY_UPDATE1 table by using below.

```
VW_HISTORY.write.mode("overwrite").format("hive").saveAsTable(s"VW_HISTORY_UPDATE1") // Now this table is having full load data.
```

Now by using below code I have loaded records from VW_HISTORY_UPDATE1 to VW_HISTORY1 table.

```
    spark.sql(s"INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE VW_HISTORY1 " +
    s"SELECT NAMED_STRUCT('IN_ID',stg.IN_ID,......) AS key, "+
    s"stg.MEM_KEY,stg.IN_OB_ID,..... from VW_HISTORY_UPDATE1 stg" )
```

I was able load VW_HISTORY_UPDATE1 table data to VW_HISTORY1. But when do same next time older records in VW_HISTORY1 are lost only new records are avaliable.

Comment: Do you send example your files? You can try use window function.

Comment: You need to know what the unique key is (the thing that defines whether two records are the same) then you can use this: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-merge-into.html

Answer (score 0):

You want to add your latest data to an existing data and while doing this you want to update records if the date is present in existing data.

Considering you do not have duplicates in either existing data or latest data, you can achieve your requirement by using the following in Databricks spark SQL.

- You can use the `ALTER VIEW` statement to achieve this because Databricks does not allow to use `UPDATE` statement on non-delta tables.
- Refer to this link to understand the `ALTER VIEW` statement: https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-alter-view.html
- First create another temporary view `full_temp` like your `full` view to avoid recursive view error while executing ALTER VIEW statement.
- Now, since you want to add data from both without duplicates, select all the records from `full` view that are not present in `update` view on a key (date) using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and combine them with the `update` view records using `UNION`. This way you get the desired result. You can use the following syntax:

```
    val solution = spark.sql("ALTER VIEW full_temp AS SELECT <columns> from full LEFT OUTER JOIN update ON full.key_column = update.key_column WHERE update.key_column is Null UNION SELECT <columns> from update”)
```

- You can now write this result Dataframe `solution` as per the requirement for further use.

Comment: Sure I will try. Also i have tried other way where, I have created two delta tables one is for full and other is for update. I am trying to Insert Overwrite update into full but my delta table with full records is getting fully overwritten where I lost full data. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Please provide sample code that you used for better understanding.

Comment: Updated in the question please check.

Comment: INSERT OVERWRITE replaces the old records completely with new records. It does not work with your requirement.